# Mysql fext search on two fields and order by number of matches

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.7

There is a table `users`. It contains a lot of fields, but we need just first_name and second name. Also on that two fields was run a search.
The search query is pretty simple:

```
SELECT 
  * 
FROM 
  `users` 
WHERE 
  `first_name` LIKE '%part1%' OR `first_name` LIKE '%part2%' OR 
  `last_name` LIKE '%part1%' or `last_name` LIKE '%part2%'
```

It's not quick, but it was enough. The problem is order by number of matches.

```
id | first_name | last_name
1  | Steven     | Smith
2  | John       | Travolta
3  | John       | Smith
```

The search string is `John Smith`. All these records are suitable, but the order is wrong. How to order the result by the number of matches?

**UPD**

```
ORDER BY
  (`first_name` LIKE '%part1%') + (`first_name` LIKE '%part2%') + 
  (`last_name` LIKE '%part1%') + (`last_name` LIKE '%part2%') DESC
```

this solution seems good, but records like `John John` and `Smith Smith` can go before the needed string

Comment: ok, my description was wrong

Comment: What order should they be in? How do we know whether John Travolta should come before or after Steven Smith?

Comment: The main goal - is to put `John Smith` to the first position.  Others records are not important

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Each of your 4 conditions returns 1 or 0 for TRUE or FALSE, so add them and sort descending:

```
ORDER BY
  (`first_name` LIKE '%part1%') + (`first_name` LIKE '%part2%') + 
  (`last_name` LIKE '%part1%') + (`last_name` LIKE '%part2%') DESC
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use NATURAL LANGUAGE PROCESSING feature of MySQL

```
SELECT * FROM users,
  MATCH (first_name, last_name)
    AGAINST ('John Smith' IN BOOLEAN MODE) as Score
 WHERE MATCH (first_name, last_name)
    AGAINST ('John Smith' IN BOOLEAN MODE) ;
```

**Notice :** InnoDB tables require a FULLTEXT index on all columns of the MATCH() expression to perform boolean queries. Boolean queries against a MyISAM search index can work even without a FULLTEXT index, although a search executed in this fashion would be quite slow.

[further information](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/fulltext-boolean.html)

> In implementing this feature, MySQL uses what is sometimes referred to as implied Boolean logic, in which

> `+` stands for AND
>
> `-` stands for NOT
>
> `[no operator]` implies OR

Comment: As I understand, there should be fulltext index on two fields?

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT *,   (`first_name` LIKE '%John%') 
          + (`first_name` LIKE '%Smith%') 
          + (`last_name`  LIKE '%John%') 
          + (`last_name`  LIKE '%Smith%') criteria
FROM `users` 
HAVING criteria > 0
ORDER BY criteria DESC
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=e600082829a6ccaa52f0c6e2c67c31df)

PS. Do you really need in LIKE? the name may be entered partially ('avol' for to find 'Travolta', for example)? maybe equiality is enough?

PPS. You may even set some matching weights (for example, the matching by first name has priority over the matching by last name) by multiplying separate expressions with according weight coefficients.

Comment: it was an old realization, so no need to change it

Comment: Which version of mysql do you use? Had issues with `pluses` - `Unknown keyword`

Comment: @V-K True, parenthesis needed (operators precedence problem). Edited... done.